# How can I define a function as an interpolant of another function in Matlab?

Tags: function, matlab, interpolation, evaluation

Suppose that I have a two-variate function, say,

```
f = @(x)(x(1).^2 + x(2).^2)
```

I want to define another function, say g, which is the first order (linear) interpolant of f at given points
X = [x; y].
For example,

```
x = linspace(0,0.5,1)
```

and

```
y = linspace(0,0.5,1)
```

In particular, I need to be able to access the values of g at a certain point. How could I define the function g?

Comment: Probably https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html.

Comment: First you need to sample your function at the given points, then define a function that uses `griddedinterpolant` and the samples. The original function is no longer needed.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hi, I tried ```griddedInterpolant(x, y, f([x;y]))``` but this gives me error: "Interpolation requires at least two sample points for each grid dimension." Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: You can start by reading the linked documentation carefully. I haven't used MATLAB in a long time but it seems clear enough that you need a "full grid" of input points (the documentation even has handy links telling you how you can do that, and it explains in clear terms what the size of those input arrays should be).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think your example `linspace` inputs are quite right, the 3rd input is how many points you want. Let's use this example with different size arrays so it's easier to see which is which:

```
x = linspace(0, 1, 3); % 3 points between 0 and 1
y = linspace(0, 2, 5); % 5 points between 0 and 2
```

You need to make them into a meshgrid format (all combinations of points) to create a 2D interpolant:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid( x, y );
```

And defining your `f` in terms of two inputs instead of a single two-element array makes it much easier to vectorise `f` so it can operate on arrays:

```
f = @(X, Y)(X.^2 + Y.^2); % vectorised function
```

Finally, you can evaluate `f` at the grid points to give "known" values `Z`. Then with `x`, `y`, and `z` you can create a `griddedInterpolant` object which lets you evaluate the grid at arbitrary `x` and `y` coordinates, using linear interpolation by default:

```
z = f(x, y); % known grid points from function evaluation
F = griddedInterpolant( x.', y.', z.' ); % make interpolation object
g = @(X, Y) F( X, Y ); % make function handle to evaluate the interpolation
```

Now you can evaluate any points you like, e.g.

```
g( 0.25, 1 )
% = 1.125
```